# CW structure from map homotopic to the identity?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes

Suppose $X$ is a $CW$ complex, and $h:X\to X$ is a (cellular) map which is homotopic to the identity.

What can one say about the the image $h(X)$? In particular I am hoping to give it some natural CW structure, hopefully homotopic to X.

As an example: if $A$ is a contractible subcomplex, applying the homotopy extension property gives a map $h:X\to X$ with $h(A)= point$, and the image of $h$ is 'morally' $X/A$ and homotopic to $X$, although this is a bit tricky to prove, and involves $A$ being contractible.

If $X$ is $k$-connected, the inclusion of the $k$-skeleton is nullhomotopic, we can apply the homotopy extension principle to get $h:X\to X$, and I would really like to conclude $X/X^{k}$ is homotopic to $X$. This is not true as written, but $X$ is homotopic to a complex with trivial $k$-skeleton. I know this can be proved with Whitehead's theorem, but can someone help me get a more ''barebones'' picture along the lines above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work in general. Let $X = D^2$ = plane disk. It contains the Hawaian earring $H$ which is no CW complex (it does not even have the homotopy type of a CW complex). We may assume that the biggest circle in $H$ is $\partial D^2$.

Give $X$ the CW structure with one $0$-cell (consisting of a point $* \in \partial D^2$), one $1$-cell and one $2$-cell. Then $X^1 = \partial D^2$.

Let $f : D^2 \to [0,1]$ be a continuous surjection such that $f(X^0) = \{0\}$ and $f(X^1) = [0,1/2]$. We can easily construct a continuous surjection $g : [0,1] \to H$ such that $g(0) = *$ and $g([0,1/2]) = \partial D^2$. The map $h = g f : X \to X$ is cellular and homotopic to the identity. Its image is $H$.

Comment: Just to be sure: why is this map (explicitly) homotopic to the identity? I suppose since we're in the disk you can contract it down to a point in the first half of the time interval, and in the second half 'undo' the contraction of the Hawaiian earring (technically, image of h, which shows this is continuous)?

Comment: @Ryan Any two map into a contractible space are homotopic.

Comment: Right, I was being longwinded that obviously generalizes. Thanks